# Phrasal verbs with "off"

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Sometimes a phrasal verb has an object. If the object is a pronoun (it/them/me/him etc.), only one position is possible. We have to put the object beetween the verb and the preposition.

For example: I'm going to ***take them off***. (not take off them)

But some phrasal verbs confuse me.

For example: In dictionaries they say ***live off sb/sth*** not ***live sb/sth off***

For example: The families are happy to ***live off them*** and use the money they earn (Why isn't it "live them off" ?

Comment: Does it make more sense when you read it as: *...to live off (of) them...?*

Comment: One general constraint on the order 'particle + object' is that it is inadmissible if the object if the object has form of an unstressed personal pronoun, but otherwise it's fine, cf."I'm going to take my gloves off" ~ I'm going to take off my gloves" is OK.

Answer (score 2):

I think the other answers have missed the fact that "to take" is a transitive verb here and therefore requires a direct object.

"to live" is an intransitive verb and *cannot* have a direct object - it may have an indirect object. On the other hand ,"to live off" is transitive and needs a direct object.

I can *take* something but I can't *live* something. I can (*live off*) something.

Comment: Hmm this really makes sense, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Because they're living off that person. That person they're living off of is the source of whatever they need to keep living.

For instance, You can't say:

> "**I'm living my father off**".

If he's paying for your stuff and giving you food, he is the source. You're living **OFF** your father. You're taking something **FROM** your father.

Answer (score 0):

> The families are going to live off of X.

*Off of X* answers the question "How are the families going to live?"  Because of that, *off of x* has to be inseparable.

> I'm going to take the gloves off.

*Off* doesn't participate in answering a *how* question here, so it can move around.